# Ventana de consola maximizada en C#

Tags: c#, consola, ventana, screen, console

Consulta... estoy haciendo un ejercicio en C# con salida por consola, y quiero que cuando se ejecute, la ventana de la consola ya aparezca maximizada en pantalla. Con la instrucción "Console.SetWindowSize(Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight);" pude hacer que aparezca en tamaño completo, pero no maximizada a la pantalla. Como tendría que hacer? agrego que estoy aprendiendo C#.

Comment: Las propiedades `maximized` o `minimized` son parte del Sistema Operativo y no puedes establecerlas mediante el objeto Console. Debes importar la librería de la API del Sistema Operativo correspondiente y trabajar con ella. Si estás en Windows, seguramente necesitas trabajar con la API de Win32. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.